# Why does the image graphic go outside its layout while inspecting in google debugger tool?

Tags: html, image, css

[image]

[image]

Hi all,
I am trying to place floorplan image (Using object tag) within the brown border in the tool i created. Then i try to display the same floorplan on the other page. But if you notice the two images i shared, border of the two floorplans within its graphic varies (Black outer border) . CSS is exactly same on both the page. I do not know what could be the reason behind the graphic shift

Comment: Can't tell until we get the actual code for it

Comment: I just want to know if theres any css or css3 property which can make the image graphic look similar to the one i shared. Because the same image when i use in another page, it just displays fine.

Comment: We just can't say without having the code used in both cases

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Images is good but we can't do much without seeing the code, so post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how the image was created. The spacing on the left side is part of the art board while the top side could be the image escaping the container.

Comment: No. I am actually using this image in some other page and it displays correctly. Now, when i position this image and trying to display it in another page it marginally shifts its position because of the graphic which did not fit properly within its container.